# 3x3 Matrix not printing in correct format

Tags: python

I am trying to create a matrix that is 3x3 but it keeps returning as one line. This is the code I have tried so far.

```
def createSymmetricMat(n):
    m = []
    for i in range(n):
        r = []
        for j in range(n):
            r.append(3*i+j)
        print()
        m.append(r)
    return m

print(createSymmetricMat(3))
```

This returns

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you're calling `print` inside your `createSymmetricMat` function and then returning `m`, which is a list of lists. the print outside of your function only prints `m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def createSymmetricMat(n):
    m = []
    for i in range(n):
        r = []
        for j in range(n):
            r.append(3*i+j)
        m.append(r)

        # print m when updated
        print(m)
    return m

createSymmetricMat(3)
```

If you want to print each time `m` is updated, just add a `print(m)` whenever `m` is updated. Then you can print the entire matrix as:

```
for row in createSymmetricMat(3):
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem with this representation of a 3x3 matrix. If you want it visually correct after you created your matrix, you can do:

```
for r in createSymmetricMat(3):
    print(r)
```

which gives you:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: This is working exactly how I wanted it too. I am not sure I understand why it is doing that though?

Comment: @Gavin you mean why it's printing it in one line? That's just how the `print` function works in python. Nothing special about it. If you want the elements in the list to be visualized in the way you want, you need to do it yourself.

Comment: If I wanted this to be a n x n matrix. How would I add the ``` for r in createSymmetricMat(n): print(r)``` to the function? so it will always return in the visually correct form?

Comment: If you want the function to return the matrix, which is a list of lists, then you won't be able to, python will always print a list of lists in the way you showed. If you want the function to print it visually correctly, then you don't need to have a return value, just follow Harshal's answer and add `print(r)` within your loop. Note that you can still have the function to return the value of the matrix.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. Making more sense now.